# Use CodeBuild triggered event HEAD_REF info as project's name subdirectories in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

I triggering a PUSH event `<^refs/head/branch$>` from GitHub to S3 using CodeBuild. I have the build successfully outputted into `bucket/projectName/` but I'll like to have the HEA_REF as subdirectories of the projectName i.e `bucket/projectName/refs/head/<branchName>/*` so each branch builds are separated.

I currently have the `$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF` and its BASE_REF counterpart. I'm wondering if this can be achieved in the console or will have to be in buildspec and how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was just to sync to the desired S3 bucket e.g

```
`- aws s3 sync ./dir/ s3://$ARTIFACTS_BUCKET/$PROJECT_DIR/$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF`
```

$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF outputs the remaining path `/refs/heads|tags/<branchName>`